# Tumblr not rendering HTML

Tags: html, tumblr

I have a HTML code to be published in my Tumblr blog. it is

```
<div style="border: #000080 1px solid; color: #000; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, Monospace; font-size: 10pt">
<div style="background: #000080; color: #fff; font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 2px 5px">Code Snippet</div>
<div style="background: #ddd; max-height: 300px; overflow: auto">
<ol start="1" style="background: #ffffff; margin: 0 0 0 2.5em; padding: 0 0 0 5px;">
<li><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#008000">// server to POST to</span></li>
<li style="background: #f3f3f3"><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#0000ff">string</span><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000"> url = </span><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#a31515">&quot;myserver.com/path/to/my/post&quot;</span><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000">;</span></li>
<li><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#008000">// HTTP web request</span></li>
<li style="background: #f3f3f3"><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000">var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);</span></li>
<li><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000">httpWebRequest.ContentType = </span><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#a31515">&quot;text/plain; charset=utf-8&quot;</span><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000">;</span></li>
<li style="background: #f3f3f3"><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000">httpWebRequest.Method = </span><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#a31515">&quot;POST&quot;</span><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000">;</span></li>
<li><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#008000">// Write the request Asynchronously</span></li>
<li style="background: #f3f3f3"><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#0000ff">using</span><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000"> (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream, httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream, </span><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#0000ff">null</span><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000">))</span></li>
<li><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000">{</span></li>
<li style="background: #f3f3f3"><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#008000">//create some json string</span></li>
<li><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#0000ff">string</span><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000"> json = </span><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#a31515">&quot;{ &#92;&quot;my&#92;&quot; : &#92;&quot;json&#92;&quot; }&quot;</span><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000">;&gt;</span></li>
<li style="background: #f3f3f3"><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#008000">// convert json to byte array</span></li>
<li><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#0000ff">byte</span><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000">[] jsonAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);</span></li>
<li style="background: #f3f3f3"><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#008000">// Write the bytes to the stream</span></li>
<li><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000">await stream.WriteAsync(jsonAsBytes, 0, jsonAsBytes.Length);</span></li>
<li style="background: #f3f3f3"><span style="background:#ffffff;color:#000000">}</span></li>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
```

but when I put this HTML code in my blog it renders as

```
<div>
<div>Code Snippet</div>
<div><ol start="1">
<li><span>// server to POST to</span></li>
<li><span>string</span><span> url = </span><span>"myserver.com/path/to/my/post"</span><span>;</span></li>
<li><span>// HTTP web request</span></li>
<li><span>var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);</span></li>
<li><span>httpWebRequest.ContentType = </span><span>"text/plain; charset=utf-8"</span><span>;</span></li>
<li><span>httpWebRequest.Method = </span><span>"POST"</span><span>;</span></li>
<li><span>// Write the request Asynchronously</span></li>
<li><span>using</span><span> (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream, httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream, </span><span>null</span><span>))</span></li>
<li><span>{</span></li>
<li><span>//create some json string</span></li>
<li><span>string</span><span> json = </span><span>"{ \"my\" : \"json\" }"</span><span>;&gt;</span></li>
<li><span>// convert json to byte array</span></li>
<li><span>byte</span><span>[] jsonAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);</span></li>
<li><span>// Write the bytes to the stream</span></li>
<li><span>await stream.WriteAsync(jsonAsBytes, 0, jsonAsBytes.Length);</span></li>
<li><span>}</span></li>
</ol></div>
</div>
```

How to get rid-of this...

Comment: Can you clarify **published in my Tumblr blog**. Is this content used in a post? If so Tumblr will strip out any inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for this, but it is very ugly.

You have to remove all your inline styles and give your html id's and classes cut and paste the new html into a blog post (make sure you select HTML in the editor option).

In the head of the main html document you now need to style the classes and id's you added to the html blog post. Go to Customise > Edit HTML.

This is a pain, but if you plan on posting similar styled content again this method would work.

I keep a working copy of the tumblr html so I can easily edit it offline and simply cut and paste the new html into the editor as and when I update it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No you would have to create custom css for this. Of course if you plan on making repeat similar posts with the same styling it would be worth doing, I think. I am constantly working on tumblr customisations so it is daily work for me.